# Что идёт после Outgoing-Call-Reply?

Tags: сервер, клиент-сервер, vpn, client

в общем делаю я VPN PPTP сервер по [этому](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2637.txt) стандарту, сейчас у меня идут следующие пакеты:

> **Client -> Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
    Length: 156
    Message type: Control Message (1)
    Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
    Control Message Type: Start-Control-Connection-Request (1)
    Reserved: 0000
    Protocol version: 1.0
    Reserved: 0000
    Framing Capabilities: Either Framing supported (3)
    Bearer Capabilities: Either access supported (3)
    Maximum Channels: 1
    Firmware Revision: 0
    Host Name: anonymous
    Vendor Name:
```

> **Client <- Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
    Length: 156
    Message type: Control Message (1)
    Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
    Control Message Type: Start-Control-Connection-Reply (2)
    Reserved: 0000
    Protocol version: 1.0
    Result Code: Successful channel establishment (1)
    Error Code: None (0)
    Framing Capabilities: Either Framing supported (3)
    Bearer Capabilities: Either access supported (3)
    Maximum Channels: 1
    Firmware Revision: 0
    Host Name: anonymouse
    Vendor Name: anonymouse
```

> **Client -> Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
    Length: 168
    Message type: Control Message (1)
    Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
    Control Message Type: Outgoing-Call-Request (7)
    Reserved: 0000
    Call ID: 63211
    Call Serial Number: 22277
    Minimum BPS: 1000
    Maximum BPS: 100000000
    Bearer Type: Either access supported (3)
    Framing Type: Either Framing supported (3)
    Packet Receive Window Size: 8192
    Packet Processing Delay: 0
    Phone Number Length: 0
    Reserved: 0000
    Phone Number: 
    Subaddress:
```

> **Client <- Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
    Length: 32
    Message type: Control Message (1)
    Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
    Control Message Type: Outgoing-Call-Reply (8)
    Reserved: 0000
    Call ID: 63211
    Peer Call ID: 22277
    Result Code: Connected (1)
    Error Code: None (0)
    Cause Code: 0
    Connect Speed: 256
    Packet Receive Window Size: 8192
    Packet Processing Delay: 0
    Physical Channel ID: 0
```

а вот дальше не понятно, что должно происходить, клиент не чего не отправляет и всё повисает? ...